# Removing wms imagery and entities with update

Tags: cesiumjs

I stuck with removing wms layer from viewer and some entities.

Adding wms works:

```
viewer.imageryLayers.addImageryProvider(layer);
```

But can't remove later from viewer:

```
imageryLayers.remove(layer);
```

Removing entities also doesn't work in my case (in [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ejovrh2/0xejoaud/1/) link you will see slider range (primitive) and it should update position/height of watertable, it is working but it is not removing previous height).

This doesn't work:

```
viewer.entities.remove(waterTable);
```

but this works:

```
viewer.entities.removeALL();
```

Please talk about logic refreshing entities. It was planned replace this slider with real live data from some sensors.

Thanks in advance, appreciate your time.

Using now latest cesium 1.75

https://jsfiddle.net/ejovrh2/0xejoaud/1/

Answer (score 1):

Answer : [fidlle](https://jsfiddle.net/ejovrh2/0xejoaud/20/)

For removing existing entities

```
if(waterTable){
 viewer.entities.remove(waterTable);
}
```

Removing wms:

```
imageryLayers.remove(layer);
```